# Edit the files with replacing string in DevOps using shell script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have created a build pipeline for Azure data factory in DevOps which will fetch the files from an azure repo.

Before deploying the changes i would like to replace few string values in some of the files located in the build artifact.

Below mentioned are the steps i followed.

1. Added a shell script file in the root folder of repository.
2. Created a build pipeline pointing to the repository branch which needs to be deployed.
3. Created a release pipeline which takes the build artifact.
4. Added an shell script in the agent job for replacing few string values from the file in the repo.

Below is the screenshot for repository structure.
[image]

After publishing the artifact in the build pipeline, below is the structure of published artifact in the pipeline.

[image]

I have added a sample shell script to the Agent job which is already in the artifact, as shown below

[image]

while running the release I am getting the below error regarding the path as shown below
[image]

How to update the files in the artifact by replacing the string values, using power shell. Does anyone have an idea how to point to the files in the artifact and run a replace script. If you could share a sample replace script by selecting the file name, it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Antony. I would like provide your another task to achieve your request, you could check my answer for some more details. If you still want to use powershell, please let me know for free.

Comment: This was helpful for string replacement during the deployment.

Comment: I have a query that at the time of ARM deployment in the prod/UAT instance, suppose if a pipeline is already running in that instance, what will happen to that pipeline/task? Will it get interrupted by the deployment or is it taken care by DevOps/ADF? @Leo Liu-MSFT

Comment: Would like open new thread for this new question, judging from the current information, I cannot understand your question. You need to open a new post to provide more specific information. I am very willing to help you.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have created a new thread for the doubt. Please have a look
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531318/will-adf-deployment-using-azure-devops-affect-existing-pipelines-jobs-in-the-env]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to update the files in the artifact by replacing the string values, using power shell. Does anyone have an idea how to point to the files in the artifact and run a replace script.

There is a great extension [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to achieve your request.

With this task, you could directly select the file/files you want to replace the strings:

[image]

We just need to replace the variables in .json file with format `#{VarValue1}#` in the repo:

like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccounts_leoteststorageaccount_name": {
            "defaultValue": "#{TestValue}#",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
```

Then define the key's values on the Variables tab:

[image]

The test result is:

[image]

This method is very simple and does not need to consider the file path, you can try it.

Comment: This was an alternate solution for my question.

Comment: @LeoLiu I haven't tested this solution yet, but what happens with those tokens in your development environment (i.e. data factory)? Do you end up having to put in working values for parameters, e.g. storageAccounts_leoteststorageaccount_name, during development and then adding the tokens during deployment?

Answer (score 2):

The above error you see in the powershell task in your release pipeline is because you pointed the `script path` to a `.sh1` file, while powershell task is expecting a `.ps1` file. Even though the path value you specified in the `script path` field is correct, powershell task will still fail with error if the file is not a .ps1 file.

If the script is bash script, you should use **[Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops)** task instead of powershell task.

You can check out below simple example in powershell script to replace a json value in artifacts file. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521035/replace-a-value-in-a-json-using-powershell/50527210).

```
$json = Convertfrom-json (get-content "_Source_alias\artifactsName\arm_template.json")

$json.parameter.value = $(PipelineVariables)

ConvertTo-Json $json -Depth 4 | Out-File _Source_alias\artifactsName\arm_template.json -Force
```

If you deploy arm template using [ARM template deployment task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md). This task allows you to replace the template parameters by configuring the `Template parameters` field and `Override template parameters` field. See below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Inside the shell script I am not able to go to the repo file location to replace the string value. How to redirect to the root folder of the repo from the shell script file?

Please use workingDirectory to navigate to where you want to have your script executed.

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\scripts\script.ps1'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\templates\'
```

What you need o remember is go give fully qualified location for you script and set working directory for a directory where your arm files are.

If you are looking for other methods you can always consider creating paramaters in your arm templates and instead replacing values just pass them as those paramaetrs.

> Is the above mentioned steps are correct for replacing a string value or do we need to publish the build first and then replace file from the artifact?

It is all up to you. You can replace strings in arm files before creating artifact or on release pipeline before running them. The questions you may ask yourself:

- will I store some secrets in I replace string before publishing artifact
- when I replace strings will I be able to deploy those string to any env or I need to make replacement once again

However, please consider adding paramaters. Maybe this is the best way.

Comment: I thought of replacing the string after build from artifacts. Updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: What your paramchanges.sh1 suppose to do? You have there piece of YAML. And you got probabaly error because you put sh1 file in powershell task. However I really don't understand what you want to achieve with this paramchanges.sh1.

Comment: powershell script should go to the arm_template.json and arm_template_parameters.json file and replace the strings from those files

Comment: I have a query that at the time of ARM deployment in the prod/UAT instance, suppose if a pipeline is already running in that instance, what will happen to that pipeline/task? Will it get interrupted by the deployment or is it taken care by DevOps/ADF?  @Krzysztof Madej

Comment: It all depends. Because some infrastructure deployment may actually delete and the create a resource. I would rather avoid to deploy both infrastructure and code at the same time. This is too risky and difficult to predict consequences.

Comment: Is there any documentation to get a clear idea about how deployments happen from devops to adf instance. And is there any way to deploy only changes through devops?