# Complete mode deployment in Azure DevOps for ADF

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I tried to deploy ARM template for azure Data Factory as part of DevOps implementation.

Mode of deployment was selected as **complete** in oreder to cleanup the existing adf instance and deploy only the pipelines that are available in ARM template. as shown below.[image]

When I tried to run the deployment, It failed with an error as

```
##[error]The deployment failed because some resources could not be deleted. This might be due to not having permissions to delete resources in the targeted scope. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
2020-11-02T05:33:34.5795133Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
```

When I did a debug on this issue, i could understand that the deployment scope is selected as **Resource Group** and deployment task tried to delete all the resources under this resource group and failed because it couldnt delete resources other than **ADF** instance because of access issues.
[image]

Since I do not have access to other resources, they were not deleted, otherwise i could have messed up everything by deleting all other resources like ADLS, databricks, sql....

Since I am deploying ADF ARM template is there any way to restrict the deployment scope only for ADF instance, which will not affect other resources.

Any leads appreciated!

I have a query about the What-If feature provided by azure for ARM template deployment. Can we use this  in our Release pipeline as a powershell task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict the deployment scope lower than the ResourceGroup as you noticed.

The only way for you to do this would be either putting the ADF in a seperate resource group but i asume that is not possible.

A second way of doing this would be deleting the ADF through the portal or powershell and then do an incremental deployment of you ARM template that has only the ADF definition in it.

Microsoft rolled out a new feature for ARM deployments called [What-If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell). This is a super nice feature to check what changes to what resources will happen when deploying your template. Note, it only works with powershell core at the moment. If you work with ARM templates this could help you and catch resource deletion before you deploy anything.

Comment: Can we use this What-If feature in our Release pipeline as a powershell task?

Comment: Sure, you can create conditions in taskgroups based for example from the output of this powershell command. In yamls however its much easier to setup conditions because you can create a condition on every task. In both cases however this requires some custom logic in powershell and assigning some value to an variable based on the what-if output and then based on that a condition for the ARM deployment itself if it should happen or not.

Comment: Could you please provide an example how to add What-If condition along with release pipeline task or Is there any document that explains how to add What-If condition in a ARM deployment pipeline? The Microsoft explanation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell] is not describing how to do it in azure devops portal.

Comment: You could set a flag "ChangesDetected" to true or false based on this chapter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell#programmatically-evaluate-what-if-results

Then set the variable in the pipeline:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts

And then use yaml conditions like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: This topic is broad and a bit problematic in classic pipelines which you are using. I would suggest migrating to yaml. They give much more control but check your requirements because they don't support everything that classic pipelines do.

Comment: Would be nice for the community if you would accept one of the answers above so people in the future with the same issue would know if this is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying a data factory, do not select **Complete** as your deployment mode. This will overwrite all resources in the resource group including non-ADF entities.

Selecting **Incremental** will deploy only the resources located in the ARM template. If generated from the adf_publish branch, then this will contain all of the resources in your factory.